# How to configure the MIME types for .net web app for using msix app package to install maui

Tags: c#, .net, deployment, maui, mime-types

I'm trying to deploy my MAUI web application on IIS web server.
The only guide I found is this : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/app-installer/web-install-iis

Unfortunately in this article used .net framework 4.7 which is not acceptable for me.
I'm trying to reproduce similar behaviour on my .NET 6 web app.

This is my maui installation page :

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}

<div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4">Welcome</h1>
    <p>Install<a href="ms-appinstaller:?source=https://localhost:7123/packages/Test.msix">MAUI</a>.</p>
</div>
```

But I'm getting this error message in msix package insulator "Error in parsing the app package.".

I'm assuming that the problem is with missed configured MIME type since I can't open the file manually from browser, but I do not understand how to configure mime types on .net 6 web app.

Guided by this article:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-8.0&viewFallbackFrom=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x#fileextensioncontenttypeprovider

I configured my static file like this :

```
var provider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();
// Add new mappings
provider.Mappings[".msix"] = "application/msix";
provider.Mappings["msix"] = "application/msix";

app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()),
    RequestPath = "/home/packages/Test.msix",
    ContentTypeProvider = provider
});


var fileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
app.UseDirectoryBrowser(new DirectoryBrowserOptions
{
    FileProvider = fileProvider,
    RequestPath = "/home"
});
```

But It still doesn't work, and I do not understand why.

I uploaded test project on GitHub : https://github.com/IgorMarkiv/mauiDeployTest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's look like ms-installer protocol was disabled by Microsoft.
I'm referring to Microsoft documentation :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/app-installer/installing-windows10-apps-web

So now I'm just downloading a regular file and opening manually.
At least until they will fix security issues.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please make sure you get the msix maui app package by the following stop : [Publish a .NET MAUI app for Windows with Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/windows/deployment/publish-visual-studio-folder?view=net-maui-7.0).

And then, I see you didn't create an **Asp.Net Web Application(.Net Framework)** but an **Asp.Net Core Web Applicaiton(Razor)**. But the [**Step 4 - Configure IIS with our Web App**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/app-installer/web-install-iis#step-4---configure-iis-with-our-web-app) is not supported in the Asp.Net Core.

So you can refer to the official document about the [Installing Windows 10 apps from a web page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/app-installer/installing-windows10-apps-web).

Finally, the first official document link you provided is too old. You can report this [on the repo](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues) to check if there any way to use it in the .net instead of .net framework.

Update:

I created a new **Asp.Net Web Application(.Net Framework)** project and got it work.

1. Get the msix maui app package by the following steps : [Publish a .NET MAUI app for Windows with Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/windows/deployment/publish-visual-studio-folder?view=net-maui-7.0).
2. Follow the 9 steps in the [Distribute a Windows 10 app from an IIS server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/app-installer/web-install-iis)
3. Enable Control Panel --> Programs --> Programs --> Turn Windows features on or off -> Internet Information Services -> World Wide Web Services -> Common HTTP Features -> Static Content.

[image]

**Note: The Static Content default disabled. You have to enable it manually.**

And my project structure:

[image]

And the result image:

[image]

Comment: To test it I've added .net framework project to repo, but I still have same error, but when I'm opening installer manually everything OK.

Comment: Please check the update part in my answer. @IgorMarkiv

Comment: I have Static Content enabled. Also deploy on .net framework is not my goal, I've added this part to my repo only to help detect the problem. I need to use this approach OR clickOnce for publish MAUI app on .NET web app.

Comment: But the asp .net core doesn't support local iis. @IgorMarkiv

Comment: What you mean local IIS is not supported by .net core?